Footprint library in Altium
Normally when download a chip library form websites, in the PCB library part in Altium, we will see 3 different footprint as follows:

What are the differences among these three?
Regards,

This should answer your question independently of any layout software: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/294894/93381

Footprint density
